# qsort and bsearch function..."pointer"

Tags: c, function-pointers, qsort, bsearch

I wonder, when we create the function

```
int compar(const void *, const void *)
```

and we merely pass its name into one of the parameters of `qsort` and `bsearch`, how do those functions recognize said essentially random word (since we've never explicitly stated it is a function pointer, but rather an actual function) and use it as a parameter? Is there an explicit cast in the function declarations of `qsort` and `bsearch` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `qsort` and `bsearch` functions themselves, rather function names are implicitly converted by the compiler into function pointers as per the standard, `C11 6.3.2.1 Language / Conversions / Other operands / Lvalues, arrays, and function designators`:

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".

That means that, when you pass `compar` to `qsort()` (for example), it's the actual pointer to the function that gets passed, not some "essentially random word".

---

The reasons for implicitly treating a function identifier as its address lie long ago in the past but (and this whole section is supposition on my part, based on what I'd like to consider intelligent reasoning, but in no way definitive) it's likely to be because the value of a function makes no sense. With an identifier `int i = 5;`, it *has* a value (5), and you can also use `&i` to get it's address.

However, for functions, they don't really have values as such. You can call them to *generate* a value, `xyzzy()`, and you can get their address, `&xyzzy`, for later calling via a function pointer.

But they have no real intrinsic *value* separate from their address like the integer `i` does. So early compilers (pre-ANSI) simply allowed the shorthand `xyzzy` to mean `&xyzzy`. And, of course, since the original mandate of ANSI was to codify existing practice rather than create a new language, they preserved this behaviour.

If K&R had gone the other way and decided `xyzzy` should be a call to the function passing no parameters, the same as `xyzzy()`, the world would be a different place :-)

Comment: well...whats the point of function pointers? Doesn't that make them obsolete? (since void is also considered a return type)

Comment: The point of a function pointer is that a single pointer may point to any function. A classic example is an array of function pointers indexed on state for a finite state machine, which lets you call one of a plethora of functions with something simple like `(fnarr[state])(payloadpointer);` In your particular case, you want to be able to call `qsort` with an arbitrary comparison function (numerics, strings, case-insensitive strings and so on). A function pointer allows you to do this.

Comment: @paxdiablo I completely forgot about the point of interchangeable parts lol..thanks for reminding me. But I guess i"ve learned something new: function names are essentially their address. like arrays